# How to get virtual output with intel + modesetting?

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, vnc

I am using an Intel embedded graphics with modesetting (e.g. xserver xorg intel driver not loaded). All is working great with internal panel on laptop, and with external displays on displayport, on hdmi.

However, I do not have a 'virtual' output (e.g. virtual1) as needed to have e.g. an vnc screen.

Its not clear how I would go about this. Some threads online discuss e.g. hijacking the unused physical output, but this has bad affects (e.g. if I use the HDMI-1 for vnc, then DP-1 breaks).

I tried adding the dummy driver, and an entry in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d, but then the Intel driver doesn't load/setup.

In Xorg.0.log, I get:

```
[   722.184] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 0
[   722.184] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 1
[   722.184] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 2
 ...
[   722.218] (II) glamor: OpenGL accelerated X.org driver based.
[   722.224] (II) glamor: EGL version 1.4 (DRI2):
[   722.225] (II) modeset(0): glamor initialized
[   722.226] (II) modeset(0): Output eDP-1 has no monitor section
[   722.272] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-1 has no monitor section
[   722.280] (II) modeset(0): Output HDMI-1 has no monitor section
[   722.281] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output eDP-1
```

This is on 17.04 with xserver-xorg 1:7.7+16ubuntu3

Does anyone have a pointer as to how to get an uncommitted virtual output available? In order to follow instructions such as [these](https://github.com/brunodles/linux-second-screen/blob/master/tutorial.md).

Comment: The post is quite old, but this procedure might work: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/585078/433757 It uses the `DisplayLink evdi` kernel module to create a dummy display without having to use the xorg intel driver or the `dummy` driver.